# Poor Parse Server performance due to Expressjs Middleware: jsonParser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, heroku, parse-server

One of my Parse Server cloud functions is performing very poorly, and I am hoping someone could help point me in the right direction to begin debugging the reasons why so I can fix it.

I used New Relic APM to do a transaction trace of the function, and can make sense of most of the numbers here, except for the culprit, which appears to be "Expressjs  Middleware: jsonParser", taking a massive 37,700 ms to complete.

Does anyone know what kind of operations could be causing that, and how I can go about fixing it? My guess would be that there is a huge JSON object passed up or down, but I am still a bit of a noob to all this web server stuff so thought I would get a second opinion, thanks! :)

[transaction trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WovSV.png)

Comment: Hello were you able to find root cause? I face the same problem in my application: https://ibb.co/vz30QnV https://ibb.co/Y2d8Yxn

Comment: I've been trying to track down similar for several years now — one theory I have is that it's mobile users on a weak connection, and it's literally the _request_ is just taking that long to come across the wire, and bodyParser can't let go of execution until it's done. We have lots of mobile users who might be in weak-connection situations, is that a possible situation for either of you that might be a commonality?